# create and configure SSL certificate not vaild certificate https red error

Tags: server, apache2, ssl, amazon-ec2, openssl

create SSL certificate and configure apache2 server in AWS EC2 instance

1. Create SSL using openssl

   ```
   sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/my-domain.key -out /etc/ssl/certs/my-domain.crt
   ```
2. Configure the apache2 server

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/my-domain.conf

   sudo a2ensite my-domain.conf

   sudo apache2ctl configtest
   ```
3. Restart apache2 server

   ```
   sudo systemctl reload apache2

   sudo ufw allow "Apache Full"

   sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/my-domain.conf
   ```

   Content of configuration file:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName my.domain.com
       Redirect / https://my.domain.com/
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerName my.domain.com
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/index.html

       SSLEngine on
       SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/my-domain.crt
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/my-domain.key
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. Save the file and restart the server
5. browser url https://mydomain.com

but not vaild SSL certificate

how to fix

Comment: Self-signed certificates are generally not valid for the reason that "anybody can make them". You will probably want to look into using Let's Encrypt, which can automate a lot of this for you.

Comment: yeah your correct anyone make the ssl certificate . i will go to vaild trust certificate providers  thank you